# Toddler cries when leaving friends

Tags: toddler, crying

My son is 3 and generally behaves well. Sometimes he will make a fuss when he wants something we wouldn't give him but nothing exaggerated.

However he always cries when leaving nursery or a friend's house and the crying increased in the last few months. The other day he met a friend at the playground and when he left my son threw himself on the ground crying.

The thing starts to be embarrassing and I am also concerned there may be a problem with my son.

Comment: Have you tried introducing the unpleasant fact gradually, e.g. 15 minutes before leaving, letting your son know that he'll be leaving in 15, then 10, then 5...? It might help him to prepare for the event.

Comment: @anongoodnurse one day the teacher saw me parking outside and just told my son "your daddy is here". He immediately started crying. So I doubt that leaving gradually would work.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is likely that your son just doesn't have the words and is therefore unable to express himself any better than a good cry. Kids go through stages. I'd try helping him with the words and providing some empathy -- like a big hug. I'm betting like other stages, he'll get through this one just fine.

Perhaps instead of saying "we are leaving", you could go and give him physical support (that hug)  and then tell him it is time to go.

The one piece of advice I'd love to be able share is that the more important we make a problem, the bigger it gets. If you don't make a big deal over it, he'll pass through it more quickly.

The 'up' side is that you are raising a sweet and caring little boy!